# Модальное окно asp net

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Я использую хелпер Beginform для отправки данных в метод контроллера, там я выполняю действия и делаю редирект(или просто обновляю страницу). Как сделать модальное окно, чтобы оно появлялась только после того как успешно отработает метод контроллера и вернёт мне новое вью?

Answer (score 0):

```
@if(ViewBag.SuccessReq)
{
    $(function(){
        $('selector').modal();
    });
}
```

На самом деле это грубый пример для грубого вопроса, нужно находить компромиссы между серверной и клиентской частью. Например отправлять запросы с помощью аякс, раз уж вы хотите показывать модальные окна, или в случае, если упор идет на серверную часть, забыть про модальные окна, и показывать результаты в новом View.